# Controlling Arrow Shape in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm making a graph that plots a host of arrows around a center, kind of like a bike tire wheel, but with the arrows pointing inward. The inputs like number of arrows etc. are all controlled through a shiny app which calls my plotting function below:

```
FPlot1<-function(arr.dat,var_explained){
  g<-rasterGrob(img,interpolate=TRUE)
  plot.grid<-ggplot(data=arr.dat,aes(colour=val))+scale_colour_gradient2(low="blue",mid="purple",high="red",midpoint=0,guide="colourbar")+theme_bw()#+coord_fixed()# +facet_grid(pc ~.)
  plot.grid<-plot.grid+
    scale_x_continuous(name="",limits=c(-7,7))+
    scale_y_continuous(name="",limits=c(-7,7))+
    geom_segment(data=arr.dat, aes(x=x2,y=y2,xend=x1,yend=y1,size=abs(val)*4),arrow=arrow(length=unit(.5,"cm")))+
    geom_text(data=arr.dat,aes(x=center+6*cos(angle), y=center+5.3*sin(angle),label=row),colour="black",size=3)+
    annotation_custom(g,xmin=-1,ymin=-1,xmax=1,ymax=1)+
    geom_text(data=arr.dat,aes(x=center,y=center,label=pc),colour="black",size=4,fontface="bold",family="Times")+
    geom_text(data=arr.dat,aes(x=xmid,y=ymid,hjust=1,vjust=1,angle=(txtangle*180/pi),label=val),colour="black",size=4)+
    theme(line=element_blank(),text=element_blank(),line=element_blank())
  return(plot.grid)

}
```

The key issue I'm having is the arrows look terrible when they get large, as per the left arrow below. I've been looking to see if there is anyway to control arrows in ggplot but have had no luck. I would prefer to stay with ggplot since having a single dataframe that controls all parts of my plot is convenient, but if I need to switch I'd understand!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Heres a quick screenshot.

[image]

The data frame that was inputed to the above function

```
structure(list(row = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("actualdisplacement", 
"LHPA_wk1", "STD_TissDeform"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(-0.75, 
-0.750000000000001, 1.5), y1 = c(1.29903810567666, -1.29903810567666, 
-3.67394039744206e-16), x2 = c(-2.5, -2.5, 5), y2 = c(4.33012701892219, 
-4.33012701892219, -1.22464679914735e-15), val = c(0.914, 0.371, 
0.068), center = c(0, 0, 0), angle = c(2.0943951023932, 4.18879020478639, 
6.28318530717959), pc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "PC1", class = "factor"), 
    xmid = c(-1.625, -1.625, 3.25), ymid = c(2.81458256229943, 
    -2.81458256229942, -7.9602041944578e-16), txtangle = c(-1.0471975511966, 
    1.0471975511966, 6.28318530717959), stringAsFactors = c(1, 
    1, 1)), .Names = c("row", "x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "val", 
"center", "angle", "pc", "xmid", "ymid", "txtangle", "stringAsFactors"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can put your image on [imgur](http://www.imgur.com) for free. What would be more useful is a [dput](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/dput) of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! If there are other things I can do to help let me know!

Comment: Please [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question